# How to set attribute values for Backbone views?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am building a Marionette item view, which is an `a` element.

I wonder how I can get valid `a` element with Mationette, because the code I have doesn't set the `href` attribute:

```
class CategoryFilters.ItemView extends App.Views.ItemView
    tagName: "a"
    className: "btn btn-primary"
    template: "topics/categoryFilter/filter-item"
    triggers:
      "click": "filter:clicked"
```

that gives the result :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary">company</a>
```

it looks ok, but this a tag doesn't have `href` attribute.

How can I set `href="#"` on this view in a clean way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-attributes) property, like...

```
attributes: { href: '#' }
```